# Selecting :after pseude element from previous element inside container

Tags: html, css

I have a given HTML code that I cannot modify:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
</div>
```

With CSS I add a label after the input (after does not work on input fields):

```
div:after { 
    content:'label' 
}
```

Now I would like to modify the label depending on the input field only, how can i select the :after element?

```
input.error + * {
    color: red;
}
```

Unfortunately i cannot use javascript, only CSS!

Comment: Not possible, you can't go up the DOM using sibling selectors in CSS. You can only affect elements that come after the element to the left of the sibling selector - not before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is impossible without adding an html element or using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to style a parent element with CSS.
You can always use js/jquery to style a parent.
`$('input').parent();`

However, in the future there will be `:has()` pseudo class, so styling a parent will look something like this:
`div:has(>input)`, which will select all divs that contain a child `<input>`.

---

If you don't want to use javascript for this. Then you will have to change the HTML.
Making the div a sibling of the input field will make it possible to use the sibling combinators:
The `+` will select only the adjacent sibling, while the `~` will look for any sibling.
I'd like to note that, it's not possible to look at the previous siblings.

Check this demo:

```css
input ~ div {
  background-color: green;
}

input + div {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>div not selected</div>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<div>div selected by both sibling combinators</div>
<div>div selected only by the general sibling combinator</div>
<div>selected also only by the general sibling combinator</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for stating. Unfortunately this is an external provided HTML sniplet, i cannot change it nor use javascript. Only styling is allowed.